# iso c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer, if statement comparing with a letter

Tags: c++, if-statement, character

I am trying to write an algorithm for calculating an ideal mass by introducing sex, age and height. My issue is obviously with the sex because its not a numerical character. I tried to introduce it with char and then, since ideal mass differs in females and males, i tried to make an if statement for each sex.
However, the conventional way i use to check equalities between numerical variables and constants doesnt work here. I kind of expected this, but nonetheless I dont understand how to fix it. I mention Im a beginner and  I dont have a good grasp on why it doesnt work. Other answers I read on this topic mention using 'string' to introduce the letter charcter. I tried that, tho I cant be sure I did it as intended, and while my programme computed then, it went over the last if statement as if it were true, althought it wasnt.

```
int main()
{
  int h, age;
  char sex;
  float masa;

  printf("introdu inaltimea: \n");
  scanf("%d", &h);
  printf("introdu varsta: \n");
  scanf("%d", &age);
  printf("introduce sexul [M/F]: ");
  scanf("%s", &sex);
  masa=50 + 0.75*(h-150) + (age-20)/4.00;

  if(sex=="M")
  {
      cout<<"masa ideala este "<<masa;
  }
  else
   masa=masa-10;
   cout<<"masa ideala este "<<masa;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `sex=='M'`.

Comment: You probably want to put braces around your `else` code too.

Comment: Yes, I forgot them for the else. And it works now, except that when I read M/F last, it cancells my age variable, meaning it takes it as 0. I solved this by moving the M/F reading to the top, and it works, but i dont understand why it does this.

Comment: Also, whats the difference between " and ' in this scenario?

Comment: @LorianaMesia `"` is for string  literals and they are constant char arrays.  `"M"` would be converted to pointer to `const char*` with value pointing at array containing `{'M','\0'}`